# Is there a legitimate principal secured fund with a guaranteed return and federally insured (not savings or mm)

Tags: investing

My grandpa insists his investment account is federally insured from loses and provides a guaranteed rate of return of 8%.

To me this sounds very Bernie Madoffy but I admit I don't know all the available financial products. I see something called a principal protected fund but that doesn't look to be federally insured.

He is also a veteran

What sort of product is he referring to?

Comment: There is no such product. This is a scam. If this existed, 90% of people's retirement savings would be in this.

Comment: That is what I said too but I thought maybe it was something subsidized for veterans or something. But I agree with you.

Comment: I suspect something is lost in translation. Perhaps the maximum return is 8%, and anything over that goes to the loss protection. If there was a guaranteed return of 8%, why would there need to be any protection against losses?

Comment: Well he just mentioned he was insured against loses. I don't think he even know what he meant but I interpreted it as if the company goes under the government steps in and reimburse any loses. The 8% was def the minimum and he claims the fund has returned "much more". Again this is an 86 year old guy so it sounds like I just need to ask him for the prospectus.

Comment: There are annuities that offer various levels of downside protection as well as  profit caps in the 6-10 pct range but they are not federally insured.  A stock paying 8% would be SIPC insured (U.S.) but not guaranteed.  All of this is guesswork.  The best thing to do is to get hold of his brokerage statement or prospectus.

Comment: He is probably invested in a fund that is guaranteed (not Federally, but by an insurer) to return at least the original amount _at the end of some fixed period of years_. There is no guarantee on the 8%, although it is not beyond the realm of possibility that it did grow 8% in the past few years. With a little luck you could do that with a 25/75 stock/zero coupon bond split. This is probably a legitimate (although maybe inferior) investment that your grandfather badly misunderstands. Whether a salesman helped him misunderstand, who knows?